# Hanvon / Hanwang Graphics Tablet not recognised

Tags: 12.04, graphics-tablet

I'm totally lost.

I've just built a new system and installed Ubuntu 12.04. It's my first time with Linux and getting into the terminal / command line for the first time since IBMDOS 5 and Windows 3.1 has been a steep learning curve.

However, the interface works beautifully apart from it doesn't recognize my Hanvon Artmaster AM1209.

I have sent diagnostics to Digimend and Favux was kind enough to advise that the tablet should be using the Wacom X driver as the Hanvon is actually a Hanwang and these should be supported.

```
lsusb reports: ID 0b57:8501 Beijing HanwangTechnology Co., Ltd  
xinput list reports:  
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2+USB Mouse                            id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Favux suggested inspecting `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for the tablet but I cannot see any mention of it, and that is as far as I have got.

I've tried researching the problem but I am struggling with all the new terminology and the fact that I want the PC to be a means to an end and not the end in itself where I spend the rest of my days tweaking and testing rather than just using it.

Hope there is some help out there.

Answer (score 1):

This was also open on launchpad.
Many, many thanks to CLAW for his time and patience. The driver on English version of the page linked by actionparsnip:
 [Hanvon Art Master Driver for Linux](http://claw.triple6.org/linux/hanvon-art-master-driver-linux/)
 was a different version to the ones I'd tried before. Initially it gave button only input on the stylus, but a clean installation of Ubuntu appears to have done the trick and I have a functioning tablet. I think my blundering about with trying to solve this problem must have destabilized ubuntu.
Thanks again to ACTIONPARSNIP & CLAW
MK

Comment: Please include details on how to use this link.